# Why is `bc` ignoring my `obase`?

Tags: unix, unix-utils, bc

```
>>> bc
bc 1.06
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
ibase = 16 
obase = 56
BE753DE5C17F1B6C9F5D1E8A628B74B0FFC4A7
 13 54 52 19 83 18 71 14 32 84 08 11 54 04 20 50 49 70 30 00 29 44 7\
7 33
```

The input is is obviously in hex. Now I assume the output are supposed to be decimal representations of "digits" in base 56. But then the highest output chunk should be 55, right? So why do I see a "83" and a "84"?

Comment: Entering “38” (hex — 3 × 16 + 8 = 56) I would expect to get “10” back. But it gives me “56” back. So what the heck, why is it ignoring my `obase` settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declaring `ibase` of 16 puts `bc` into hex mode, so your next line:

```
obase = 56
```

is actually interpreted as hexadecimal: `0x56` = 86 in decimal, which is why your output "digits" include values up to but no larger than 85.

Swapping the order in which you declare `ibase` and `obase` solves this:

```
obase = 56
ibase = 16
BE753DE5C17F1B6C9F5D1E8A628B74B0FFC4A7
 01 27 46 38 00 54 21 49 15 55 31 13 08 39 08 26 31 35 14 01 25 24 0\
6 13 11 36 07
```

and:

```
38
 01 00
```

Comment: (Was really confused at first but edited your answer for clarity after realizing what you meant! Thanks!)